# Delay Backbone.sync events

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jquery-deferred, backbone-events

I have a custom Model class in which I have a property that tells me when the model was last fetched:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    fetched: null,
    fetch: function(options) {
        var self = this;
        return Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch
            .apply(this, arguments)
            .done(function(){
                self.fetched = _.now();
            });
    }
});
```

Then, my View listens to this model's `change` events and renders itself when that happens, with a different result depending on whether the model has been fetched or not:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    },
    render: function() {
        if (this.model.fetched == null) {
            // Do something
        }
        else {
            // Do something else
        }
        return this;
    }
});
```

My problem is that the `change` event is triggered as soon as `Model.fetch` is completed, even before I set `self.fetched = _.now()`.
I know I could trigger the event manually at this point, but that would be redundant, plus I'm not sure that the model actually changed during this fetch.

Is there a way to catch the events that are triggered during the call to `Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch` so I can trigger them manually in my chained `done`?

**Update**: Or, is there a way to give `fetch` a function to run on success before it fires the events?

Comment: It's not what it was meant for, but overriding [parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) would let you run code before data is applied to the model.

Comment: @ivarni Yes, from what I see in the source it is the only place where I can *insert* instructions right before the `change` event is triggered (see line 592 [here](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/00f8b6fe797321131f76a72e95560ad2354c5dc9/backbone.js#L592), the event is triggered when `model.set(serverAttrs, options))` is executed). However, at this point I will know that the data has been successfully received from the server, but not if it has been successfully `set` to the model. I'm starting to think that the only way to achieve what I want is to rewrite `Backbone.Model.fetch`.

Answer (score 1):

The timing is out because the `.done()` handler fires in a later event thread, similar to a `setTimeout()`.

> Is there a way to catch the events that are triggered during the call to Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch so I can trigger them manually in my chained done?

Not, I expect, without hacking Backbone, which you really don't want to do. However you can exploit Backbone's ability to trigger, and listen to, *custom events*.

For example, you can have a custom `fetched` event, triggered from the .done() callback in `MyModel.fetch()`, and listened to wherever you like.

The need for your `MyModel.model.fetched` timestamp will disappear because, unlike `change`, the custom event will only ever be triggered from that one place.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    fetch: function(options) {
        var self = this;
        return Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch
            .apply(this, arguments)
            .done(function() {
                self.trigger('fetched');
            });
    }
});
```

Although the documentation talks of custom events only in connection with `.on()`, they can equally be listened to with `.listenTo()`. And there's nothing to prevent you listening to the standard `change` as well as the custom `fetched` event.

This strategy would allow (for example) your "Do something" and "Do something else" to be performed in separate listeners, rather than as branches of a single listener :

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render_on_change);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'fetched', this.render_on_fetch);
    },
    render_on_change: function() {
        /* Do something */
    },
    render_on_fetch: function() {
        /* Do something else */
    }
});
```

The variations are endless. You will probably need to play around with it until you get exactly what suits your app.

In order to introduce `this.listenTo(this.model, 'fetched', ...);`, I'm afraid you will have to bite the bullet and make changes to every view that need to respond to that event. That's unavoidable.

On a positive note, any models which currently have `this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', ...);` and don't need to listen to `fetched`, can remain as they are.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply the fetch function a success callback and you can get rid of the code in your model.

```js
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        var self=this
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
        this.model.fetch({
            success: function(){
               self.model.fetched= _.now();
        })
    },
    render: function() {
        if (this.model.fetched == null) {
            // Do something
        }
        else {
            // Do something else
        }
        return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: I see two problems with this solution: I have to do it in every view that listens to my model, and it won't work if the model is updated after the view has been rendered.